# How can I declare a Pair array using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to do something like this: (the code is in java)

```java
Pair[] pairs = new Pair[1];
```

I want to convert this code to kotlin, the problem is I don't know how to initialize this array.
This is the code I have:

```
val prof_intent = Intent(this, NewObjectiveActivity::class.java)
    val pairs = arrayOf(1)
    pairs[0] = Pair<View, String>(fabNewObjective, "activity_trans")

    val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, pairs)
    startActivity(prof_intent, options.toBundle())
```

Comment: `val pairs = arrayOf(Pair<View, String>(fabNewObjective, "activity_trans"))`

Comment: I tried that, but in the line ```val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, pairs) ``` it gives me this error "Types mismatch. Required: android.util.Pair<View!,String!>! ; Found: Array<kotlin.Pair<View, String>>"

Comment: `makeSceneTransitionAnimation()` does not take an `Array<Pair>`. It takes a varargs of `Pair`. Since you only have one `Pair`, just pass the `Pair` to `makeSceneTransitionAnimation()` and remove the `arrayOf()` part. Or, try passing `*pairs` to use the "splat operator" to expand the array into arguments.

Answer (score 8):

**First Solution:**

You can define an array list of pairs as you had in your java code in this way:

```
val pairList = ArrayList<Pair<String, Int>>()
```

Then you can define your variable and add it to your list:

```
val pair = Pair("hi", 12)
pairList.add(pair)
```

**Second Solution:**

```
var pairs = arrayOf(Pair("hi", 12), Pair("bye", 13))
```

**Third Solution:**

```
pairs = arrayOf("hi" to 12, "bye" to 13)
```

Comment: or... `arrayOf("hi" to 12)`

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the pairs in the method indicating each pairs with their index number.

The method `makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity activity, Pair<View, String>... sharedElements)` in the `ActivityOptions` class requires an activity as the first parameter and could have as many pairs as possible as the following parameter.

See the code below for a better understanding:

```
val pair = listOf<Pair<View, String>>(
             Pair<View, String>(img, "image_shared"),
             Pair<View, String>(txtview, "text_shared"),
             Pair<View, String>(imgView, "image_view_shared")
         )

         val options: ActivityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, pair[0], pair[1], pair[2])
         Intent(this, SharedElementActivity::class.java).also {
             startActivity(it, options.toBundle())
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

To give an example that's then used in an activity transition:

```
var pairs = arrayListOf<Pair<View,String>>()
for (view in listOfViewsToBeTransitioned) {
    val transitionPair = Pair.create(view, view.id.toString())
    pairs.add(transitionPair)
}

val pairsArray:Array<Pair<View,String>> = pairs.toTypedArray()
val transitionOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, *(pairsArray))

val intent = Intent(this, targetActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent, transitionOptions.toBundle())
```

The `*` splat operator expands a typed `array` into the varargs that `makeSceneTransitionAnimation` will accept. This example also assumes there is a meaningful value in `view.id`, I generally make this the resource identifier of the drawable used in the view.

Comment: correct *pairs.toTypedArray() works

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Documents](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity#start-with-multiple) , it's better to do like this :

```
// Rename the Pair class from the Android framework to avoid a name clash
import android.util.Pair as UtilPair
...
val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
        UtilPair.create(view1, "agreedName1"),
        UtilPair.create(view2, "agreedName2"))
```